# Как реализовать избирательную камеру(Three.js)?

Tags: webgl, three.js, разработка-игр, javascript

**Gizmo** - элемент управления привязка которого делается к определенной опорной точке объекта. За Gizmo можно перетаскивать, вращать и масштабировать объект (прямая аналогия с 3DSM, Maya и им подобным)

Есть две сцены на одной находятся **объекты** (кубы, шары ...) на другой объект **Gizmo**.

```
updateWorld: function(){

    this.orbitCameraControl.update(); // обновляем контроллер камеры(OrbitControls.js)

    this.renderer.clear();
    this.renderer.render(this.sceneObject, this.camera); // рендерим сцену с объектами
    this.renderer.clear(false, true, false); 
    this.renderer.render(this.sceneGizmo, this.camera);  // рендерим сцену с Gizmo
}
```

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

на второй картинке видно, что при приближении камеры размер объектов обеих сцен меняется.

**Как сделать** так что бы объекты на обоих сценах при изменении положения (**перенос, поворот, Zoom**...) камеры,  вели себя как всегда, лишь с тем отличием что **приближение и удаление камеры не сказывалось** на объекте **Gizmo**?

Другими словами, чтобы **Gizmo** не **Scale'лся** и не **Zoom'ился** и оставался всегда одного размера

Comment: при движении камеры считать расстояние и скалить объекты самому ?

Comment: поясните пожалуйста как это сделать?

пробовал нечто подобное если я вас правильно понял, но так как обе камеры(отдельно камера на объект, отдельно на gizmo) имеют тип perspective, имея одну и ту же точку просмотра(но разную позицию) получается искажение такого характера:
http://i7.pixs.ru/storage/3/2/1/Bezimyanni_2119671_10164321.png

Comment: я никогда не видел чтобы подобные вспомогательные элементы не искажались от перспективы камеры (и это правильно - они же показывают направления осей),  насчет как сделать я не знаю, т.к. не знаю как вы показываете сцену.

Comment: Прошу прощения я не правильно выразился. Смысл в том что бы камера относительно gizmo(вспомогательного элемента)выполняла поворот и перенос данные искажения имеют смысл. Не приемлемое искажение в данном случае - это приближение и отдаление от точки просмотра, необходим алгоритм расчета позиции gizmo, чтобы gizmo был всегда равно удален от точки просмотра(позиции камеры)